# PNG in ImageView has black background

Tags: android, android-imageview

My imageview is set to a bitmap that is a PNG. But problem is that the transparent part is black. I've set background to @android:color/transparent and #00000000, but it is still black. I've tried to search but nothing helped. Thanks in advance!

Here's are the xml of the imageView with it's parents:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/mainbg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/vbTempLink"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:background="@color/mainbg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tempImage1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

I set the png with these codes (bg is string):

```
background.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapToDrawable((bg)));

public Drawable bitmapToDrawable(String s) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path + s);
    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    return drawable;
}
```

And yes the image surely has a transparent background.

Comment: Did you run you app with a new device?

Comment: Where do you set the png? and show us also the parent of the ImageView. Probably the parent is black

Comment: Is your **png** file TRANSPARENT (i.e.: is it on a layer, not on a background)? And is the background DELETED?

Comment: I don't know why you put transparent. I think by default that is transparent. Please update with total file.

Comment: updated. and yep, the file is updated

Comment: android:background="@color/mainbg" what is the color is that represents. ?

Comment: @Nava2011 it is #272a36.

Comment: Change that to #00000000 and run it once. I think your color code is almost back that color is coming.

Comment: Do you need to define your PNG programmatically that way?

Comment: @masmic_87 yes, i do.

Comment: @Nava2011 nothin changed.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but think that defining your image as drawable that way is what is making not to have a transparent background

Comment: @masmic_87 made me think, and tried setBackground instead of setBackgroundDrawable but still the same.

Comment: Please explain the purpose of setting the image with drawable that way, maybe you can do it in another way (adding more code would help)

Comment: @masmic_87 because images that are set are variables. i have a template and different images are shown on that imageview.

Comment: IMO when converting the image to a drawable it is some way defining a background for the drawable and that's why your image seems to have a background color even if it is transparent. I would recommend you to try to do it in another way

Comment: Well if you want to mantain the transparent background you could do 2 things: first is define a transparent drawable and then set the image there (never tryed and not even know if it can be done, but you could try). And the second would be to define the images directly `.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable._____));` Before doing extra job, you can check first to set that image in this way and see if it solves the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that it was on how i compressed the bitmap.

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
```

No other way but to find another way. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6):

I know this is very old post but this might help others..

From your code I can clearly see that you are retrieving your image from local storage and not from Android resources.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path + s);
```

So I think you are trying to retrieve JPEG compressed image. **File extensions are meaningless if it has been stored with some other compression formats**.

If you want to store and retrieve PNG images then store your source images in PNG format and then retrieve it.

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
```

Because by default JPEG compression would store transparent background pixels in black color. So better avoid compressing it as JPEG.

Comment: But that is what it was. The fix was to format it to JPEG. It worked.

Comment: "Because by default JPEG compression would store transparent background pixels in black color. So better avoid compressing it as JPEG."  is absolutely true. I had png image, i was compressing it with jpeg, hence the background was coming black. Changed to .png compression resolved the issue.

Comment: @RaghavSharma, Dude! How to get the image with Transparency just like WhatsApp Stickers. After doing with .PNG, still the black background.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that if you want the png background to be transparent is because there is something else behind. Then, I made the transparent stuff work with this:

```
Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
layers[0]=resources.getDrawable(colour);
layers[1]=resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.somethingToBeDrawn);
(someView).setImageDrawable(new LayerDrawable(layers));
```

where `colour` is the picture from behind, in my case a green or grey colour's png (that's way it's called "colour").